# Assertion failed in compareHist (opencv)

Tags: java, opencv

i have the following code and i have tried to make it in CV_32F but still it gives me this error:

```
        Mat A = Highgui.imread("letter12.jpg", Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
        Mat B = Highgui.imread("r3.jpg", Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

        Mat resizeimage = new Mat();
        Size sz = new Size(A.width(),A.height());
        Imgproc.resize( B, resizeimage, sz );


        A.convertTo(A, CvType.CV_32F);
        resizeimage.convertTo(resizeimage, CvType.CV_32F);

        double distance = Imgproc.compareHist(A, resizeimage, Imgproc.CV_COMP_CORREL);
```

Error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (H1.type() == H2.type() && H1.type() == CV_32F) in compareHist, file Desktop/opencv-2.4.8/modules/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp, line 1985
error: cv::Exception: Desktop/opencv-2.4.8/modules/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp:1985: error: (-215) H1.type() == H2.type() && H1.type() == CV_32F in function compareHist
```

Comment: You should at least call `calcHist` to calculate the histograms of your images before attempting to compare them. I suggest you [look at some sample code](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html) to make sure you understand the required steps.